# How to receive ECHO signal from HCRS04 sensor by STM32L010

Tags: c, stm32

I beginner from this. I use IDE CUBEMX + Nucleo64 STM32L010RB board and HCRS04 sensor. In project I use Timer22; Prescaler 8-1; Counter period 65535; and UART2 and also PIN7 as output for Trigger. The ECHO signal of the sensor is connected via a voltage divider from 5 volts to 3 volts. I will want to received ECHO signal, but all the time I have value "0". This is one file from my trying example. Please to show me where is my mistake.

```
#include "main.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "stdio.h"

uint32_t captured = 0;
uint32_t value_1 = 0;
uint32_t value_2 = 0;
uint32_t difference = 0;
uint32_t distance = 0;
char TX_Data[25];

TIM_HandleTypeDef htim22;
UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;

void SystemClock_Config(void);
static void MX_GPIO_Init(void);
static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void);
static void MX_TIM22_Init(void);

void delay (uint16_t time)
{
    __HAL_TIM_SET_COUNTER(&htim22, 0);//Set the TIM Counter Register value on runtime.
    while (__HAL_TIM_GET_COUNTER(&htim22) < time);//Get the TIM Counter Register value on runtime
}

int main(void)
{

  HAL_Init();
  SystemClock_Config();
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_USART2_UART_Init();
  MX_TIM22_Init();
  HAL_TIM_IC_Start_IT(&htim22, TIM_CHANNEL_1);

  while (1)
  {
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_RESET);//Clears the selected data port bit.
      delay(2);
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_SET); //Sets the selected data port bit.
      delay(10);
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_RESET);//Clears the selected data port bit.
      __HAL_TIM_ENABLE_IT(&htim22, TIM_IT_CC1); //Enable the specified TIM interrupt. Capture/Compare 1 interrupt

      sprintf(TX_Data, "Distance (cm)  = %lu\r\n", distance);
      HAL_UART_Transmit_IT(&huart2, (uint8_t*)TX_Data, sizeof(TX_Data));
      HAL_Delay(500);
  }
}

void SystemClock_Config(void)
{
  RCC_OscInitTypeDef RCC_OscInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_ClkInitTypeDef RCC_ClkInitStruct = {0};
  RCC_PeriphCLKInitTypeDef PeriphClkInit = {0};

  __HAL_PWR_VOLTAGESCALING_CONFIG(PWR_REGULATOR_VOLTAGE_SCALE1);

  RCC_OscInitStruct.OscillatorType = RCC_OSCILLATORTYPE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSIState = RCC_HSI_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.HSICalibrationValue = RCC_HSICALIBRATION_DEFAULT;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLState = RCC_PLL_ON;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLSource = RCC_PLLSOURCE_HSI;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLMUL = RCC_PLLMUL_4;
  RCC_OscInitStruct.PLL.PLLDIV = RCC_PLLDIV_2;
  if (HAL_RCC_OscConfig(&RCC_OscInitStruct) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }

  RCC_ClkInitStruct.ClockType = RCC_CLOCKTYPE_HCLK|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_SYSCLK
                              |RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK1|RCC_CLOCKTYPE_PCLK2;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.SYSCLKSource = RCC_SYSCLKSOURCE_PLLCLK;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.AHBCLKDivider = RCC_SYSCLK_DIV1;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB1CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV8;
  RCC_ClkInitStruct.APB2CLKDivider = RCC_HCLK_DIV1;

  if (HAL_RCC_ClockConfig(&RCC_ClkInitStruct, FLASH_LATENCY_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  PeriphClkInit.PeriphClockSelection = RCC_PERIPHCLK_USART2;
  PeriphClkInit.Usart2ClockSelection = RCC_USART2CLKSOURCE_PCLK1;
  if (HAL_RCCEx_PeriphCLKConfig(&PeriphClkInit) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

static void MX_TIM22_Init(void)
{

  TIM_ClockConfigTypeDef sClockSourceConfig = {0};
  TIM_MasterConfigTypeDef sMasterConfig = {0};
  TIM_IC_InitTypeDef sConfigIC = {0};

  htim22.Instance = TIM22;
  htim22.Init.Prescaler = 8-1;
  htim22.Init.CounterMode = TIM_COUNTERMODE_UP;
  htim22.Init.Period = 65535;
  htim22.Init.ClockDivision = TIM_CLOCKDIVISION_DIV1;
  htim22.Init.AutoReloadPreload = TIM_AUTORELOAD_PRELOAD_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIM_Base_Init(&htim22) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sClockSourceConfig.ClockSource = TIM_CLOCKSOURCE_INTERNAL;
  if (HAL_TIM_ConfigClockSource(&htim22, &sClockSourceConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  if (HAL_TIM_IC_Init(&htim22) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sMasterConfig.MasterOutputTrigger = TIM_TRGO_RESET;
  sMasterConfig.MasterSlaveMode = TIM_MASTERSLAVEMODE_DISABLE;
  if (HAL_TIMEx_MasterConfigSynchronization(&htim22, &sMasterConfig) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  sConfigIC.ICPolarity = TIM_INPUTCHANNELPOLARITY_RISING;
  sConfigIC.ICSelection = TIM_ICSELECTION_DIRECTTI;
  sConfigIC.ICPrescaler = TIM_ICPSC_DIV1;
  sConfigIC.ICFilter = 0;
  if (HAL_TIM_IC_ConfigChannel(&htim22, &sConfigIC, TIM_CHANNEL_1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

static void MX_USART2_UART_Init(void)
{

  huart2.Instance = USART2;
  huart2.Init.BaudRate = 9600;
  huart2.Init.WordLength = UART_WORDLENGTH_8B;
  huart2.Init.StopBits = UART_STOPBITS_1;
  huart2.Init.Parity = UART_PARITY_NONE;
  huart2.Init.Mode = UART_MODE_TX_RX;
  huart2.Init.HwFlowCtl = UART_HWCONTROL_NONE;
  huart2.Init.OverSampling = UART_OVERSAMPLING_16;
  huart2.Init.OneBitSampling = UART_ONE_BIT_SAMPLE_DISABLE;
  huart2.AdvancedInit.AdvFeatureInit = UART_ADVFEATURE_NO_INIT;
  if (HAL_UART_Init(&huart2) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
}

static void MX_GPIO_Init(void)
{
  GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};

  __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOA, Green_LED_Pin|GPIO_PIN_7, GPIO_PIN_RESET);

  GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = Green_LED_Pin|GPIO_PIN_7;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT_PP;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_NOPULL;
  GPIO_InitStruct.Speed = GPIO_SPEED_FREQ_LOW;
  HAL_GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStruct);

}

void HAL_TIM_IC_CaptureCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim)
{
    if(htim->Channel == HAL_TIM_ACTIVE_CHANNEL_1)
    {
        if(captured == 0)
        {
            value_1 = HAL_TIM_ReadCapturedValue(&htim22, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
            captured = 1;
            __HAL_TIM_SET_CAPTUREPOLARITY(&htim22, TIM_CHANNEL_1, TIM_INPUTCHANNELPOLARITY_FALLING);
        }
        else if(captured == 1)
           {
               value_2 = HAL_TIM_ReadCapturedValue(&htim22, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
               __HAL_TIM_SET_COUNTER(&htim22, 0);

               if(value_2 > value_1)
               {
                   difference = value_2 - value_1;
               }
               else if(value_1 > value_2)
                   {
                       difference = (65535 - value_1) + value_2;
                   }

              distance = difference * .034/2;
              captured = 0;

              __HAL_TIM_SET_CAPTUREPOLARITY(&htim22, TIM_CHANNEL_1, TIM_INPUTCHANNELPOLARITY_RISING);
              __HAL_TIM_DISABLE_IT(&htim22, TIM_IT_CC1); //Disable the specified TIM interrupt. Capture/Compare 1 interrupt
           }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Serhii welcome to SO! you should check this page: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking as it contains a lot of informations that can better your question in order to get more views and get the problem solved

Answer (score 0):

Hmm try to check:

- Is the trigger signal properly formed ( on oscilloscope or logic analyzer)
- next if previous Ok, try to log response on echo pin ( oscilloscope or logic analyzer)

If mesurements will OK you can try to manually generate signal on timer input...